# Erro na instalação do Rust no windows 10

Tags: rust

Estou dando meus primeiros passos na linguagem. Já li boa parte da documentação e resolvi instalar na minha máquina.
Baixei o [rustup-init aqui](https://www.rust-lang.org/pt-BR/install.html).
Porém, quando executo o instalador tenho o seguinte erro:

`error: could not download file from 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256' to 'C:\Users\fernando.cavalcante\.rustup\tmp\mbkyn0d_zdlnhsfl_file'
info: caused by: error during download
info: caused by: [35] SSL connect error (schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - A fun��o de revoga��o n�o p�de verificar a revoga��o do certificado.)`

Como prosseguir?

Comment: `SSL connect error`, o problema é na conexão. Só por via das dúvidas, checa se o horário do sistema está correto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É um problema de SSL na sua conexão.
Você pode estar usando uma conexão corporativa ou compartilhada que tem restrições de proxy ou firewall. Tenta fazer usando uma conexão direta padrão. Tipo 4G ou sua Wi-Fi de casa mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou instalar usando o msi installer?

[Outros métodos de instalação](https://www.rust-lang.org/pt-BR/other-installers.html)

Observação: Se você escolher a versão "windows-msvc" precisará instalar o Visual Studio (15)2017 ou ao menos o BuildTools dele somente. Caso contrário use o "windows-gnu" mesmo.